# Footer image at the bottom of the page

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-aura-components, pdf

I have a VF page that is rendered as pdf, on that page I have a footer, which I want to display at the end of the page. Currently, it's appearing wherever the page body is ending.

How to fix the image at the bottom of the page.?

VF Page:

```
<apex:page renderAs="pdf">
  <head>
                <style type="text/css" media="print">
                       
                       div.footer {
                                display: block;
                               position: running(footer);
                               page: lastPage; 
                      }
                    </style>
              </head>
  
  <div style="text-align:center;" class="footer">
      <apex:image url="{!$Resource.Footer}" width="539.04px" height="18.48px"/>
  </div>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the element in the @page media CSS:

```
@page {
  @bottom-center {
    content: element(footer);
  }
}
```

In addition to the styles you've already defined.

You can read more about it this [Help topic](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000326128&type=1&mode=1).

Comment: here what is bottom-center? will it be my style class

Comment: @sfdc It's the position of where you want the footer. You can read more about it in [the specifications](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-page-3/).